# Shapes.Rectangle или Drawing.Rectangle?

Tags: wpf, производительность, графика

Обращался к интернету, там сказано, что на WinForms сейчас программируют только дриопитеки и уже как 10 лет используют WPF.

Ок! Решил в плане самообразования сделать `Rectangle` с полупрозрачным контуром и заливкой на `Canvas`, который можно тянуть за все стороны, перетаскивать и т.д. используя `Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` (WPF же)

Но что то мне подсказывает, что этот прямоугольник какой то тормозной в плане отрисовки.

Даже `label` который прицепил к позициям курсора, немного отстаёт от самого курсора при быстром движении.

А так же `BackGround.Window` на 3840 точек в ширину и 1080 в высоту заливается c помощью `<SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.10" Color="Black"/>` тормознуто.
Не хоп и сразу залит, а прям видно как заливается при появлении окна xD

И это i7-6700k с gtx 1070

Судя по всему надо использовать всё таки `System.Drawing` для 2-D графики и подобных задач ?

Comment: Скорость процессора тут не при чем, WPF использует аппаратное ускорение, так что всё упирается в производительность вашей видеокарты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, использование прозрачности требует серьезных затрат ресурсов. Тем более при отрисовке окна таких размеров (с высокой вероятностью 3840 х 1080 выходит за пределы максимального размера, поддерживаемого аппаратным ускорением видеоадаптера, и [WPF переходит в режим программной отрисовки](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf/)). Однако, в Windows Forms вообще нет поддержки прозрачности в той мере, как в WPF, поэтому такое сравнение несколько некорректно. Кроме того, WPF обладает другими преимуществами, например, векторная графика и возможность декларативного описания объектов в виде XAML. Я бы сказал, что следует изучать все же WPF, если нет какой-то особой причины оставаться с WinForms.